# Performing algebra on random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am currently taking a probability course. The proof of Chebyshev's inequality goes like this:
$$
\mathbb{P}\left( \left| Y - \mathbb{E}Y\right|  \geq \epsilon\right) = \mathbb{P} \left( \left[ Y - \mathbb{E}Y\right]^2  \geq \epsilon^2\right) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}(\left[ Y - \mathbb{E}Y\right]^2)}{\epsilon^2} = \frac{\operatorname {var}(Y)}{\epsilon^2},
$$ 
where the second inequality is justified with Markov's inequality. I am not sure why the second inequality is valid. For example, 
$$
\mathbb{P}(0 \leq X \leq \epsilon) \neq \mathbb{P}(|X| \leq \epsilon)
$$
even if $0 \leq x \leq \epsilon \to |x| \leq \epsilon$. So, in general when is $\mathbb{P}(X \leq \epsilon) = \mathbb{P}(f(X) \leq f(\epsilon)$ true? My answer is that when $f$ is invertible. In other words then $f(x) \leq f(\epsilon) \iff x \leq \epsilon$. This comes from the fact that
$$
 \mathbb{P} (\{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega)<\epsilon\}) =    \mathbb{P} (\{\omega \in \Omega: f(X(\omega))<f(\epsilon)\})  \iff f^{-1} exists?    
$$
OR if $x<\epsilon \iff f(x)<f(\epsilon)$? Am I correct?

Comment: Invertible and increasing will work. Note both sides in the chebyshev proof are positive, hence $x^2$ is both invertible and increasing when restricted to this domain.

Comment: @ArtimisFowl, if it's decreasing on the domain then you just flip the inequality, right?

Comment: yep, you can see this quickly via noting that if $f$ decreasing then $-f$ is increasing, and then simplifying the inequality.